# Secrets as environmental variables in vstest

Tags: azure-devops, vstest

In my tests I'm using environmental variable. Due to security reasons, when setting it in azure devops pipeline I need to mark it as secret. Is it possible to pass it as argument, within vstest task?

Comment: Can you show how you use this variable in your tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been through this. There's no way to pass variables to VSTest on the command line, which means you have to jump through a few hoops.

You have a few options:

- Use a runsettings file with a `TestRunParameters` section, then access it via `TestContext.Properties["variableName"]` within the tests themselves. You can use standard token replacement patterns to transform the XML file.
- Use an app.config or appsettings.json (depending on your platform). This works pretty much the same as above, except, of course, you use the standard configuration classes to retrieve the values.
- Add a step to your pipeline that sets the appropriate environment variables. Secrets don't get *automatically* mapped to environment variables for security purposes, but there's nothing that's stopping you from doing it yourself.
- Move the secret values into a keyvault or some other sort of external secret storage and configure the test to pull the secrets at runtime.

Comment: there is also one more option, described here https://gavincampbell.dev/post/vsts-secret-environment-variables/  It works but seems kinda dirty to me.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently lacking enough reputation to comment on the answer by @daniel-mann, I need to follow-up through an answer myself.

**Regarding the use of a runsettings file;**

Yes, I'm sure you can do it like this, but there's a much simpler way. In the task definition, you have the option to override test run parameters.

For a non-YAML pipeline, you do this in the "Override test run parameters" option (the tooltip says "*Override parameters defined in the TestRunParameters section of runsettings file or Properties section of testsettings file. For example: -key1 value1 -key2 value2.*"), so like this then:

```
-SomeSecret $(SomeSecret)
```

For a YAML-pipeline, you can do this:

```
overrideTestrunParameters: '-SomeSecret $(SomeSecret)'
```

The nice thing is that the test run parameter that you'd like to override DOES NOT need to exist in your runsettings file. In fact, there's not even need for a runsettings file at all!

The bad thing about this approach in general is that you'll have to access your secrets through the "`TestContext.Properties`" collection (for NUnit), which really sucks if you want a transparent solution that works equally well both for local development (using "user secrets") and in an Azure pipeline.

Another potentially bad thing about this is that these "overridden" test run parameters are just that - parameters for THAT test run only. If you happen to have a mixture of .NET Framework and .NET Core tests, you would want to execute those in two different test runs (for it to work at all...), and then you'd need to duplicate those overrides (given that some of the same secrets are needed, that is).

**Regarding adding an additional task in your pipeline to set the appropriate environment variables;**

Absolutely. Using the "Batch script" task is well suited for this, where you just pass your secret-based variables as parameters to the script and pick them up inside the script file.

For this to work as expected, though, you will need to allow the task to modify the environment.

For a non-YAML pipeline, this is done by ticking off the "Modify Environment" checkbox.

For a YAML pipeline, you could do it like this:

```
- task: BatchScript@1
  displayName: 'Export key vault vars as env. vars (for tests)'
  inputs:
    filename: 'ExportKeyVaultEnvironmentVariables.cmd'
    arguments: '$(SomeSecret)'
    modifyEnvironment: true
```

Where in the "ExportKeyVaultEnvironmentVariables.cmd" script, you just do this:

```
set SomeSecret=%1
```

**Note:** If your secret by chance has some funny characters, especially having a trailing "=" character, you might experience that what you get when collecting the parameter inside the script is NOT what you sent in.

You can avoid this problem by enclosing the parameters in double quotes, like this:

```
arguments: '"$(SomeSecret)"'
```

And then collect the parameter by removing those surrounding quotes by using the "~" parameter modifier, like this:

```
set SomeSecret=%~1
```

A nice bonus effect of this approach is that your shiny new full-blown environment variables persist for the remainder of your pipeline. Referencing back to my "bad thing" about having to potentially duplicate the test run parameter overrides, that would not be needed here.

**Regarding the additional option mentioned by the OP;**

Absolutely, in which case you wouldn't need a "Batch script" task (that needs to call a script file), but just a "Command line" task.

BUT, be aware of a possible gotcha! Yes, this will create an environment variable for your test code to pick up, if you access it through "`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`".

In my case, I was building an "`IConfigurationRoot`" instance, like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a configuration instance, based on user secrets (for local test execution) and environment variables (for Azure pipeline execution).
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the class that represents the "runtime" (and thus is able to get hold of any configuration).</typeparam>
/// <returns>An <see cref="IConfigurationRoot"/> instance.</returns>
public static IConfigurationRoot GetConfigurationRoot<T>()
    where T : class =>
    new ConfigurationBuilder()
        //// Note: The "AddUserSecrets" method requires the "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" package
        .AddUserSecrets<T>()
        //// Note: The "AddEnvironmentVariables" method requires the "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" package
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
```

This works by adding various "configuration providers", which eventually allows you to access them all seamlessly through "`configuration["SomeSecret"]`".

What I found, though, if I'm not seriously mistaken, is that "SomeSecret" was still not available in the "`EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider`" that's added, even though I could perfectly fine access it directly with the above mentioned method. Go figure (but I might be mistaken...).

**Possible alternative approach (but for YAML pipelines only?);**

It seems that for a YAML pipeline, you can explicitly set environment variables for a task, like this:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  env:
    SomeSecret: $(SomeSecret)
[...]
```

I haven't tested this myself, but seen a colleague do it (myself, I currently don't have a YAML pipeline). At least this variable can be picked up with "`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`", but I don't know if this can be picked up through an "`IConfigurationRoot`" instance.

I haven't seen any option to achieve the same in a non-YAML pipeline.

But again, this also suffers from the same possible "having to duplicate the environment variables across several test runs" problem.

**See also my solution to my own question over at the [Azure DevOps guys](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/1266612/view.html)**